# Incomplete trace of a function

Tags: metapost

Why the curve is not drawn to the point x1 ?

```
 \starttext
 \startMPcode
  xmin := -1; xmax := 5; ymax :=4 ;ymin:=-4; u := 1cm;
  pickup pencircle scaled 1pt ;
  a:=2-sqrt(3);
  b:=2+sqrt(3);
  def compute_curve(suffix f)(expr xmin, xmax, xinc) =
  ((xmin,f(xmin))
  for x=xmin+xinc step xinc until xmax:
  .. (x,f(x))
 endfor )
enddef;
vardef f(expr x) = x*x-4*x+1 enddef;
path pts_f;
pts_f := compute_curve(f, a, b, .1) scaled u;
path axe_x,axe_y;
path screen;
screen=(xmin,ymin)*u--(xmax,ymin)*u--(xmax,ymax)*u--(xmin,ymax)*u--cycle;
axe_x = (xmin,0)*u -- (xmax,0)*u;
axe_y = (0,ymin)*u -- (0,ymax)*u;
drawarrow axe_x; 
drawarrow axe_y;
draw pts_f withcolor blue withpen pencircle scaled 1pt;
label.lrt(btex $x_1$ etex,(a,0)*u);
label.lrt(btex $x_2$ etex,(b,0)*u);
draw (a,0)*u withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
draw (b,0)*u withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
clip currentpicture to screen;
\stopMPcode 
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `a=0.26794` and `b=3.73206`, so incrementing by `0.1` leads to a final point with `x=3.66815`, because `3.66815+0.1>b` (consider also the rounding errors).

You should call

```
pts_f := compute_curve(f, a, b, (b-a)/50) scaled u;
```

to get 50 points (you can decide the amount of sampling).

[image]

[image]

Using `mpost -numbersystem=double` could be even more precise (I don't know how to enable it in ConTeXt): we'd have

```
a=0.26794919243112281
b=3.7320508075688772
(b-a)/50=0.069282032302755092
```

The last point used has

```
x=3.7320508075688732
```

With the default number system we have

```
a=0.26794
b=3.73206
(b-a)/50=0.06927
```

and the last point used has

```
x=3.73169
```

Comment: @egregThank you, but I had to solve this problem, I must be tired !